# Why jQuery Mobile displays table wrong?

Tags: jquery, mobile, reflow

Why is my Table displaying wrongly? On the Demo Page is it nice, but on my code looks bad.
Can you help me? I use the actual jQuery 1.4.2

My file is here: http://stratisoft.ch/phpbuilder/users/user2/termin/test.html

and the working demo here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/tables/table-reflow.html

This looks bad:

[sieht nicht gut aus http://stratisoft.ch/phpbuilder/users/user2/termin/doof.png](http://stratisoft.ch/phpbuilder/users/user2/termin/doof.png)

And this looks nice:

[sieht gut aus http://stratisoft.ch/phpbuilder/users/user2/termin/gut.png](http://stratisoft.ch/phpbuilder/users/user2/termin/gut.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want additional padding to separate each entry?  If so, try using `<th>` as the first entry of each row as in the jQuery example.

```
<tr>
<th><span>Sa. 3.2.2007</span></th>
<td><span>thun</span></td>
<td><span>Musik</span></td>
<td><span>Hans Muste.</span></td>
<td><span>00</span><span>:</span><span>00</span></td>
<td><span>00</span><span>:</span><span>00</span></td>
<td><a href='/phpbuilder/users/user2/termin/edit.php?changebut=107&tabelleEvents=1&backward=1&us=1&' class="editbut win7but">&Auml;ndern</a></td>
<td><a href='/phpbuilder/users/user2/termin/edit.php?delbut=107&tabelleEvents=1&backward=1&us=1&' class="editbut win7but">L&ouml;schen</a></td>
</tr>
```